# How to create update to your app

Tags: android, eclipse

Not sure if my question makes any sense but still..
Lets say I created and released app for android. I use android:versionCode and android:versionName in the manifest to track version of the app. Now, i want to update my app by releasing new version (but keep an old version as well ). How should i do that in eclipse? should i copy my project, paste it with new name and make all changes in there? or is there more elegant way to manage versions of the same app in eclipse?

Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is the reason u want to keep the old version?

- Is it purely for a version control perspective? If yes, use git (http://git-scm.com/) to do version control.
- If you're gonna have a different version of the app (e.g. free and paid), unfortunately Eclipse have no way of handling that and you'll need a copy, but if you're willing migrate to Android Studio, it does have the concept of flavors

Comment: I made an app that is good enough to use. its only for a local use in a company, so its not for google play. I installed it in devices i need, and now i want to add some more functions to it, but i don't want to mess around with currently working code. I guess best way is to copy/paste my project - keep developing the clone, and leave original code as is.

Comment: on that situation, it's the 1st bullet point I put. You want to have a version control system on your app. Which I suggest use GIT, although there're others. Those systems remember changes and don't need to hassle to re-setup re-copy the project. Also they only write in disk, what really changed, that way you don't have to duplicate information all the time.

Answer (score 1):

you will need a new bundle identifier, so yes, you have to create a new project.

Answer (score 0):

One common way is to set a Settings file held in a server that keeps your application settings plus your version code. This way you can force the user to do stuff like force update, or completely close your application.

Comment: But of course, that will also mean that your users will require an internet connection to open up your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can get close to what you want by keeping different branches in your version control system (git, svn, etc...) and use merges to keep all the branches updated.